# Pure reducers and canvas context?

Tags: reactjs, redux, html5-canvas

I'm creating a MS Paint replica. After a week of messing around with React states, I wanted to go with Redux. The problem I think of is: How can I pair a reducer which must be pure, with a canvas context which basically has its own state (what is drawn on it)? I see two options here:

1. Do I need to recreate canvas context every time the state changes? If so, I do think this is really redundant practice.
2. Or can I just carry the context between states and use its methods to draw in reducers as I'd usually do? But this makes my reducers impure as I understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've chosen to store ImageData (getting it via context `getImageData` method) in Redux store. This keeps the store serializable and immutable. I face some troubles with performance though, because `getImageData` and `putImageData` are very slow, so I need to update ImageData in my store as rarely as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the canvas context can't be easily serialized and it's not the "source of truth" in terms of application state (rather an object created by the native browser api). Therefore I'd only use redux to have undo/time travel functionality. Your reducer would only hold a history of drawing actions. Replaying those on an empty canvas should restore the state of the app.

Comment: For now I'm going to hold an ImageData of my context in the store. ImageData is based on Uint8ClampedArray so it is serializable as I understand. My action creators are using that ImageData by putting it to the context, drawing something on it, and dispatching the changed ImageData in an action. Is this approach right enough?

Comment: The ImageData, singular? That sounds like a bitmap of all pixels on the canvas. I guess that would work for undo, since you could go back to a previous state, which is basically a snapshot of the entire canvas. This might accumulate a lot of data though if the canvas is big. The links in the answer above are probably your best bet, this is kind of an exotic use case in my opinion. Good luck though!

Comment: It's just too complicated for me to make a state as a sequence of every single canvas action of the user at this moment. So I'll have just an ImageData for now (yes it's just an array of rgba values of all pixels), it's simpler to wrap my head around and does its job. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The canvas represents the UI of your application, and shouldn't be kept in the store itself.  Since a canvas retains whatever pixels have already been drawn, what you probably need to do is re-execute your drawing logic whenever the store has been updated.

There's a pair of posts out there that demonstrate how to use a Redux store to drive drawing on a canvas as the UI:

- [A Functional Canvas Approach with Redux, Part 1](https://medium.com/@peterxjang/a-functional-canvas-approach-with-redux-ce59a369241b)
- [A Functional Canvas Approach with Redux, Part 2](https://medium.com/@peterxjang/a-functional-canvas-approach-with-redux-bab357d6c33c)